# Method as target of {if} in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

Is there a way to use a method call of an object as the target of a conditional in a Smarty template?

As a concrete example, I have an object `$user` with a method `loggedIn()`. I want to use this method to show extra info if the user is logged in.

I can assign the return value of this method to a temporary variable and use this as the target of `{if}`:

```
{user->loggedIn assign="loggedIn"}
{if $loggedIn}
  // show extra info
{/if}
```

Is there a way to skip this intermediate step? I'd like something like this (doesn't work):

```
{if user->loggedIn}
  // show extra info
{/if}
```

I can't find any examples of using objects like this in Smarty's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`assign_by_ref`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.assign.by.ref.php) instead of `register_object`:

```
$smarty->assign_by_ref('user', $user);
```

Then you can access methods:

```
{if $user->loggedIn()}
    // show extra info
{/if}
```